# How to stop / destroy a running operation in c#

Tags: c#

I have a windows form with a start and cancel button.

The start button does the following:

```
bootLoader = new BootLoader(this, _form1);
bootloader.Start();
```

Now when the user clicks the start button, the BootLoader class writes data to the COM port.

What I want to know is that how can I stop this operation from completeing when the user clicks the  cancel button.

Currently I just have the following:

```
this.Close();
```

But It just closes the form and the data carries on being written to the com port.

Comment: What is `BootLoader`? Is it a form?

Comment: You can use a Task to do this. [How to: Cancel a Task and Its Children](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537607(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @noelicus it is just a c# class that performs operation's on the com port

Answer (score 1):

Use a cancellable [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

```
var bw = new BackgroundWorkder();
bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
```

Then in your `DoWork` worker function you'll need to monitor the `CancellationPending` flag which will become true after you call `bw.CancelAsync()`.

Comment: If you suggest `BackgroundWorkder` it is worth mentioning that he will need to monitor the `BackgroundWorker.CancellationPending` property and quit the job himself in case of a cancel...